# Does Zoom speed up if people turn off their cameras?

Tags: zoom-meeting

I was recently in a 500+ person conference call on Zoom, and someone made a comment that everyone should turn video off to stop lag/speed up the call.

I'm just wondering how valid that statement was? Because whether there are 20 videos or 200 videos, it's all being compiled and sent on as a single video via Zoom's servers, right? So my video shouldn't affect someone else's call?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference. The audio is there or not. Maybe it uses more local resources and can make one persons computer seem slow if there is a bunch of video, but it wouldn't affect most people.